# Paper for Custom Book Jackets?

Tags: paper, book-binding

I wanted to make a custom book jacket, but I'm not sure what paper to use. Any help would be great. I live in the UK so if you know what the paper is called over here that would be even more amazing.

I'd preferable want something with a matt finish that I can print on. I'd also like it to be relatively durable.

Another possibility I'd considered was paper than transfers onto hard cover but I have no idea where to start with that.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for a particular type, weight, texture, and/or finish for the book jacket? What are you making it from (drawing directly on, printing, painting, other)? The more detail you include ([edit] your question) the better responses you'll get :)

Comment: You can also protect the book cover and the jacket surface by simply wrapping the jacket you make in a paper-backed mylar jacket cover, like libraries use.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider [Kraft-Tex® Paper](https://www.ctpub.com/kraft-tex/).  Many people are using it for bookbinding.  It is also used for making wallets, purses, even luggage.  It is ultra-durable (virtually rip-proof), can be sewn like fabric, and embellished in many ways including printing.  Here is the description written by the manufacturer, C&T Publishing:

> Wait until you get your hands on this rugged paper that looks, feels, and wears like leather, but sews, cuts, and washes like fabric. Kraft-Tex® is supple, yet strong enough to use for projects that get tough wear. Use it to bring an exciting new texture to your craft-sewing projects, mixed-media arts, home decor, and bookmaking. Durable fiber-based texture softens and crinkles with handling and washing.
>
> Original unwashed Kraft-Tex® is available in Black, Chocolate, Natural, Stone and White by the bolt or by the roll. (It is now available in several more colors.) So many ways to play with Kraft-Tex®: sew it, stamp it, paint it, fold it, draw or inkjet-print on it. White is a wonderful canvas for painting, rubber stamping, drawing, and stitching. Black makes metallic ink or thread, gel pens, and powdered pigments pop! Kraft-Tex® does not require interfacing.

I have purchased some and can’t wait to see what it is like to work with!

Answer (score 0):

Elephant Hide, also known as Wyndstone Marble, is a very strong bookbinding paper which you might find in some art supply stores and online.